# Downscope Azure SQL Server permissions

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

While running on an app service in Azure, I would like to use the managed service identity to authenticate against Azure SQL Server with two sets of permissions. Within my service I'd like to have a read/write DBContext and a readonly DBContext. Is there a way to downgrade access after authenticating?

I don't necessarily have access to an AG with a readonly replica so I don't think I can use `applicationintent=readonly` and `EXECUTE AS` only seems to apply in a stored procedure or function.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question....When setting up an MSI on the SQL server then the Identity is managed in SQL like any other user where SQL scripts can be ran to assign the user permissions.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to segregate my app logic to have a read surface (API) and a write surface (inbound service bus messages). Without two different permission levels the API would have write access as well.

Comment: 2 MSIs?  I suggest you get this working without MSIs first, as you can easily do this with 2 logins/2 users in SQL

Comment: Oh, we definitely can just use usernames and passwords, that seems very straight forward. Are Azure App Services capable of getting two identities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about EXECUTE AS not working outside of a stored proc/function (I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/customizing-permissions-with-impersonation-in-sql-server) documentation to be misleading, and later found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

As such, I ended up going with the following solution:

1. Create a read-only user with no login

   ```sql
   CREATE USER [readonly_user] WITHOUT LOGIN
   ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [readonly_user]
   ```
2. I create an interceptor that looks for the `applicationintent=readonly` flag to be set in the connection string

   ```cs
   public class SessionContextDbConnectionInterceptor: DbCommandInterceptor {
     /// <inheritdoc />
     public override Task<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
       DbCommand command,
       CommandEventData eventData,
       InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
       CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()) {
       if (eventData.Connection.ConnectionString.Contains("applicationintent=readonly",
                                                          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
         command.CommandText = $"EXECUTE AS USER = 'readonly_user';\n{command.CommandText};\nREVERT;";
       }
       return base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Then register the interceptor with the DB context

   ```cs
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
       .AddInterceptors(new SessionContextDbConnectionInterceptor()));
   ```